# Query regarding a desired feature in PySimpleGUI TK version

Tags: input, graph

I have built a graphic oriented package using the Graph element.  I need to do keyboard input based on Graph Element coordinates.  Currently I am using the events that come in from the keyboard to place characters on the Graph element using draw_text.  It works but is a bit slow and I get into problems with interpreting the key codes I get back from different platforms and the overhead with me doing the echoing back on to the Graph element does not help.

My Question.  In PySimpleGui(Tk) is there a way to use the Tk Entry function directly on Graph Coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it can be done like your request, but much complex.

Here only a simple way to enter text on a Graph element.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font = ('Courier New', 16, 'bold')

layout = [
    [sg.Input(expand_x=True, key='INPUT')],
    [sg.Graph((320, 240), (0, 0), (320, 240), enable_events=True, key='GRAPH',
        background_color='green')],
]
window = sg.Window('Draw Text', layout, margins=(0, 0), finalize=True)
entry, graph = window['INPUT'], window['GRAPH']

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'GRAPH':
        location, text = values['GRAPH'], values['INPUT']
        if text:
            graph.draw_text(text, location, font=font, color='white', text_location=sg.TEXT_LOCATION_LEFT)

window.close()
```

[image]

Here, something like your request, but much complex and tkinter code required.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def entry_callback(event, graph, entry_id, font, location, color):
    widget = event.widget
    text = widget.get()
    graph.widget.delete(entry_id)
    if text:
        graph.draw_text(text, location=location, font=font, color=color, text_location='sw')

font = ('Courier New', 16, 'bold')

layout = [
    [sg.Graph((320, 240), (0, 0), (320, 240), enable_events=True, key='GRAPH',
        background_color='green')],
]
window = sg.Window('Draw Text', layout, margins=(0, 0), finalize=True)
graph = window['GRAPH']

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'GRAPH':
        location = tuple(map(int, graph._convert_xy_to_canvas_xy(*values['GRAPH'])))
        entry = sg.tk.Entry(graph.widget, font=font, fg='white', bg='green', width=45)
        entry_id = graph.widget.create_window(*location, window=entry, anchor="sw")
        entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event, graph=graph, entry_id=entry_id, font=font, location=values['GRAPH'], color='white':entry_callback(event, graph, entry_id, font, location, color))
        entry.focus_force()

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You Jason.  That is close to what I was striving for.  What I have works, but is painfully slow.